# Using ExtJS 4 charts with Ext.Net (coolite)

Tags: charts, extjs4, ext.net, coolite

I'm hoping to be able to  load an ExtJS chart inside Ext.Net(coolite) pages. 
I've copied the pie chart from the ExtJS samples and have put it in an test aspx document to see it work:

heres is my pie.aspx

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pie Chart</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ExtJs4/ext-all.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Ext.Loader.setConfig({
            enabled: true,
            disableCaching: true,
            paths: { 'Ext': "/app/" }
        });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ExtJs4/resources/CSS/ext-all.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ExtJs4/examples/shared/example.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ExtJs4/examples/example-data.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/pie.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="ExtJs4/bootstrap.js"></script>



</head>
<body id="docbody">

</body>
```

when I try and load it from an Ext.Window I dont see anything just an empty popup. if I go to the url directly i dotn see anything either

Here's the code I'm using to attempt to load the chart (i put it inside my existing coolite code):

```
<ext:Window
            Title='!'
            runat="server"
            AutoDataBind="true"
            Modal="true"
            ID="ChartWindow"
            Width="900" 
            Height="670"
            Hidden="false">
                <AutoLoad Url="pie.aspx" Mode="IFrame" />
        </ext:Window>
```

Am I going about this the wrong way in trying to using the Ext.Net dll with the new ExtJS libraries? Is there another way I could go about accomplishing the same thing (ie: have a server-side window to load the ExtJS 4 charts)?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved!!
not sure what was the problem,my code is correct,maybe only the cache

Comment: You should explain what you did to solve the problem for people with the same issue

Comment: my code is correct i didnt change anything.it just worked after i cleared the cache and restarted